# I have error when i am calling my local asp.net web api in angular js5

Tags: angular

This is my code and I am getting this Error (Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:53915/api/EmployeesCrud. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

[image]

Comment: Did you enabled CORS in your API?

Comment: CORS needs to be enabled in your backend. Also, there is no such thing as 'Angular js 5'. It's just Angular.

Comment: Add this in your `WebApiConfig.cs` file `var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");  config.EnableCors(cors);`

Comment: Thank You Amit Kumar and Aamir Khan . with this I solve my error

Comment: Amit Kumar can you guide me how can I put data in asp.net web api from angular js 5